# Is there a canonical (no pun intended) source for Ubuntu version badges?

Tags: packaging, github

I just added a Debian version badge (from https://badges.debian.net/) to my font (https://github.com/rbanffy/3270font/tree/develop), and, since it's also available on Ubuntu, I'd like to add one too. Is there an official badge generation service for Ubuntu?